# Visualizing nets in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, geometry, nets

What is the best way one can visualize the concept of a net or a subnet in a given topological space $X$? What is the intuition that makes sence when thinking about the definitions of convergence and cluster points of a net? I understand that the convergence concept derermines the topological structure of $X$ by looking at thd theorems but I can't see how is this working and what is really going on beneath. I think once I can develop an intuituon around nets, subnets and cluster points, I could see everything more clear.

Comment: The intuition for nets in general topological spaces is pretty much the same as the intuition for sequences in metric spaces.

Comment: It's sort of like a sprawling, non-linear, non-countable version of a sequence. There can be lots of branches but these always come together again (the directedness of the index set ensures this), so that tails always meet. Intuition for nets is acquired from studying proofs where they're used, not the other way round typically. It's a convenient technical tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have though about the question and now I think I have developed a good intuition about the concept. Indeed as @HennoBrandsma has mentioned in the comments, intuition comes from studying how they interact in the structure of a proof. The following is what I realized earlier today when I was trying to prove these two statements:

> A point $p$ in a topological space is a cluster point(points that each
> open set $U$ containing $p$ contains all the terms of the net
> eventually) of a net $\{x_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ if and only if
> $\{x_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ has a sub-net
> $\{x_{\alpha_{\beta}}\}_{\beta \in J}$ such that
> $\{x_{\alpha_{\beta}}\}_{\beta \in J} \longrightarrow p$.

> Let $X$ be a topological Space, then $X$ is Compact if and only if
> every net in $X$ has a sub-net converging to a point.

While proving the first statement I was first choosing terms like $x_{\alpha_{U}}$ to be any point inside an open set $U$ containing $p$ in vain. I was trying hard to prove that this should be a sub-net while all along it wasn't. I believe one important fact is that you understand that in case of a net, when you are trying to find a sub-net(which is basically finding a sub-directed set in the original directed set) choosing infinitely many indices from the index set $I$ isn't going to automatically give you a sub-net! This is important and it is a big difference with sequences. I believe my confusion was coming from this illusion that I had.

To show why this is actually the case Let's look at this picture:

[image]

The concept of a directed set is the generalization of $\mathbb{N}$. Indeed I think we can add a concept of infinity point for directed sets which I define it as follows:

> Define a mere symbol $\infty$ and add it to the directed set. you can
> still define the partial ordering by saying $\forall x \in D \quad x <
>  \infty$ (here, $D$ is the directed set). The condition that $\forall
>  x, y \in D - \{\infty\}  \quad \exists z \in D  - \{\infty\}
> \quad z > x, z > y$
> simply means that
> the points on $D$ are moving towards this $\infty$ point as they get
> bigger.

This pic also shows why just choosing infinitely many members do not end up as a good sub-index! you may really end up with another directed set (as I did) but this subset's infinity may not be the same as before. For example the rectangular part in the picture could be itself a manifold and has infinitely many points but all of them be on a certain level in the partial ordering so that they are not even comparable. This is why in the definition of sub-net you are required to choose indices $\alpha_{\beta}$ such that for each $\alpha \in I$, there is a $\beta_0$ such that $\beta > \beta_0 \Longrightarrow \alpha_{\beta} > \alpha$.

Before writing this answer, I also thought of this very last condition as follows. I add another symbolic point $-\infty$ and think of it as a source, for example a faucet containing some water. As the water passes through $\mathbb{N}$ or $D$ it naturally makes some points wet. But it never stops on some specific region (like the rectangular aria that could be a manifold) since the source of gravity ($\infty$ symboll) always pulls it down. This naturally gives you a sub-net.

[image]